# Delete last object from the array of objects.

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, object, underscore.js

I have this array of objects and i would like to delete the last object. i.e. 2 from the list. Can someone please let me know to do this.

```
Object {Results:Array[3]}
Results:Array[3]
[0-2]
  0:Object
         id=1     
         name: "Rick"
         Value: "34343"
  1:Object
         id=2     
         name:'david'
         Value: "2332"
  2:Object
         id=3
         name: 'Rio'
         Value: "2333"
```

Comment: You want to delete the object at index 2 in all cases, or the last object, or the object with an `id` of 3, or delete it based on what other criteria? A simple approach is `obj.Results.length--`.

Comment: `results.splice((results.length - 1),1);`

Comment: `results.pop()`

Comment: `results.length--` would do it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could just [**splice**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) out the last element in the array:

```
obj.Results.splice(-1);
```

```js
var obj = {
  Results: [{
    id: 1,   
    name: "Rick",
    Value: "34343"
  }, {
    id:2,
    name: 'david',
    Value: "2332",
  }, {
    id: 3,
    name: 'Rio',
    Value: "2333"
  }]
};

obj.Results.splice(-1);
console.log(obj);
```

Answer (score 10):

Try using the [`.pop()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Array/pop) method. It'll delete the last item of an array.

```
obj.Results.pop();
```

Answer (score 3):

You can [`pop()`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_pop.asp) the last item out of the array.

```
obj.Results.pop()
```

For more on array methods, visit [this](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_array.asp).

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Array.prototype.splice` to remove the last item.

```js
var data = {
  Results : [ {
    id    : 1,  
    name  : "Rick",
    Value : "34343"
  }, {
    id    : 2,
    name  :'david',
    Value : "2332"
  }, {
    id    : 3,
    name  : 'Rio',
    Value : "2333"
  }]
};

var removed = data.Results.splice(-1,1);

document.body.innerHTML = '<pre>'+ JSON.stringify(data, null, 4) +'</pre>'
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use [array.pop()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/pop) for it, it removes the last element and returns it.